# Books on delay / lag compensation

Tags: control-systems, reference-request, delay

Which books do you recommend that provide comprehensive overview of delay compensation techniques in control systems?

Comment: Sounds like you need any good control system theory book. I can only recommend German ones – that's what I read. Otto Föllinger – Regelungstechnik is my go-to book.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the standard is Ogata's "Modern Control Engineering".

I also recommend Franklin/Powell/Emami-Naeini's "Feedback Control of Dynamic Systems".

For a more basic introduction you might consider Nise's "Control Systems Engineering", but I'm not a fan of his writing style.